# Upgrade drupal 7 to backdrop

Tags: migration, drupal-7, backdrop

I am trying to upgrade a Drupal 7 site with CiviCRM to backdropCMS, but am struggling.

Am looking https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switching-cms/drupal-to-backdrop/ and https://docs.backdropcms.org/documentation/step-3-upgrade-the-drupal-site

Am not switching drupal to backdrop, am upgrading it.

What I did sofar:
Leave civicrm module and webform_civicrm module enabled, upgrade to backdrop.
Tried to install an empty backdrop, because of https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switching-cms/drupal-to-backdrop/
Which failed, because civicrm does not want to install, it asks for a civicrm.settings.php

I created it, filled in the empty civicrm database, that did not work. Used the existing civicrm database, disabled civicrm and enabled again. Now Civicrm seems to start working.

But webform_civicrm data seem completely lost.

How should I do the upgrade from D7 to Backdrop and preserve CiviCRM and webform_civicrm data and functionality?

Answer (score 1):

@Catorghans, starting a community wiki here with your response on the Backdrop Zulip chat (feel free to edit/expand):

> - Yep, this is a working procedure: first create a `civicrm.settings.php` in `backdrop-root/`
> - leave `civicrm` module enabled. Use the same CiviCRM version for Backdrop as you had for Drupal 7
> - run the Backdrop upgrade.

This also means that webform_civicrm does a proper upgrade.